# Is it okay to define objects globally that I will not use again?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an amateur game and when the player enters the game for the first time there will be a selection screen that will be brought up. There are some objects for this selection screen. (For example 8 rectangle objects) Once the selection is made, the player's selection will be saved and we will not need these 8 rectangles again.
My question is:
Where should I define these 8 rectangles in my main class? Is it okay to define objects globally that I will not use again?
I will use these rectangle objects in only these two methods:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
    // if-else and do-somethings
}

private void mouse_buttonCheck() {
    Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, 1, 1);
    // if-else and do-somethings
}
```

If there was only one method that I am using these 8 rectangles, I would define and initialize them inside the method. However, since there are two methods and I will only use it at the very beginning of the game, I did not know if it would be right to define and initialize globally.

Comment: Why dont you create them as a field inside the class that will use them? Do some proper OOP.

Comment: It is kinda impossible to give you architecture advise without seeing the rest of the code base and architecture.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with defining such variables "globally" but I don't see such variables in your sample, those rectangles seem to be dependent on other variables

Comment: @JimmyT. Since I don't know where to place the 8 rectangles I mentioned, I couldn't put it in the sample code.

Comment: @Zabuzard My code is very long, so I tried to make it understandable by giving the necessary part. In short, I have a main class and I will use these 8 rectangles in only 
two methods.

Comment: @Zabuzard By field do you mean code blocks? Like: { My Rectangles; Method1{ }; Method2{ }; }

Comment: No, I do not mean code blocks. I literally mean fields, also called members. You might want to step back from this and first practice some more OOP.

Comment: Creating them locally seems just fine, and probably preferable.  You should define variables in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I had only one method, I would do this, but since I have 2 methods, I cannot define my 8 rectangles inside the method. How else to define them locally? Or by local do you mean defining it as a variable of the class?

Comment: If it's shared between two methods, then you have little choice but to make it a field.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I got it thank you. Here's what she says about Field on the internet: Field is generally a private variable on an instance class. It does not mean there is a getter and a setter. So in short what you mean is defining my rectangles as a private member of my class, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would put them inside a private *static* nested class. This way, you can separate these eight fields of objects from the rest of the code.

```
class OuterClass {

    // private static nested class
    private static class ObjectsWrapper {
        public static Rectangle mouseRect1;
        public static Rectangle mouseRect2;
        /*
        * the other objects, in total 8 of them
        */
    }

    @Override
    public static void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
        // if-else and do-somethings
    }

    private static void mouse_buttonCheck() {
        Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        Rectangle mouseRect = new Rectangle(p.x, p.y, 1, 1);
        // if-else and do-somethings
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't make any difference in performance, but it will make the code more organized, right?

Comment: @HangeZoë yes, exactly. It is meant to organize the code. You can only access the rectangles inside the private static nested class by referencing the class name first and not directly. For example: "ObjectsWrapper.mouseRect1 = ...". You can also only access them inside the OuterClass class, since the ObjectsWrapper class is private.

Comment: I think I will define my rectangles as fields for now, but this is a really nice method for organize, thank you.